# How to efficiently display different UIViews in a collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to display different kind of charts (Bar, Pie, Donut) in a collection view which are different UIView's ! As of now, I add those views, setup some constraints and remove the views for every cell. This seems to be really against the concept of reuse ! How do I do this efficiently in a collection view ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option you can use in order too maximise maintainability is to create different UICollectionViewCells with Xib files.